# blank image shown while using picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

Here using an adapter to load the images in the `RecyclerView` and here is the code I am using to load the Image from the URL

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("IMAGE URL")
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)  
.error(R.drawable.error)     
.into(holder.stud_photo);
```

Comment: Is this same code are you using or have you replace your original image url with `"IMAGE URL"`

Comment: Can you please provide one of image url?

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: [you can implement this for picasso...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270474/adding-4mb-image-from-url-to-imageview-in-android-studio/42271248#42271248)

Comment: have you added internet permission to your manifest file?

Comment: no i have another url from the server side

Comment: share your image url

Comment: Share the exact url that you are passing as param

Answer (score 1):

**you can implement this for Picasso**

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(foodItem.getImageUrl())
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .error(R.drawable.logosign)
                .noFade()
                .into(holder.productImage);
```

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: how can i use memoryPolicy() and networkPolicy() ?? ,  it shows error in my code

Comment: update this in gradle compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'